# ASP.NET - Iframe Equivalent to Display Multiple Gridviews using Ajax or UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, iframe, updatepanel

Question:

- Is there an equivalent for HTML's IFrame in ASP.NET?
- If so, could you provide some example code on how to implement this?
- What would be the best approach for trying to convert the following Access VBA Runtime into an ASP.NET Page?

Here's a screenshot of the Access Runtime Application:

[image: App Screenshot]

The User selects Search Criteria:

- State
- Zip Code
- Plan Code (D, F, G, M, N)
- Carrier Name (Optional)

Male / Female Lowest Rate table displays:

- Lowest Rate
- Carrier Name
- for each Insured Age (65, 70, 75, & 80)

All Rates Table displays:

- ALL Carrier Names
- Insured Age (65, 70, 75, & 80)
- Rate Costs for Male and Female

Carrier Information table (when user clicks on a carrier name) displays:

- Street Level Compensation Year 1
- Policy Fee
- Spousal Discount
- Website
- Insurance Rate Effective Date
- Insurance Rate Change History

Any helpful answers will get an up-vote! 
Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bunch of positioned `div`s to me, using CSS it should be doable. Also using `UpdatePanel`s, likely.

#### Sample HTML & CSS

Note, this is a quick sample to get you started but is probably NOT perfect!

```
<?DOCTYPE html>

<html xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body
            {
                margin: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            div
            {
                border: 1px solid Green;
            }

            div#Page
            {
                display: table;
                width: 100%;
                height: 80%;
            }

            div#Top
            {
                display: table-row;
            }

            div#Top div#Left,
            div#Top div#Middle,
            div#Top div#Right
            {
                display: table-cell;
                width: 33%;
            }

            div#Top div#Left div#Logo
            {
                height: 100px;
            }

            div#Bottom
            {
                height: 20%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Page">
            <div id="Top">
                <div id="Left">
                    <div id="Logo">
                        Logo Here
                    </div>
                    Carrier...
                </div>
                <div id="Middle">
                    Search
                </div>
                <div id="Right">
                    The red stuff...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Bottom">
            Grid...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Result

[image: Doesn't it look lovely?]

Comment: thanks for your response. Can you give me some sample code for this?

Comment: how would i incorporate this code into the existing CSS - 
#Table1 { height: 119px; width: 33%;  } .style2 {
            height: 39px;
            width: 15%;
        }
        

        .style3
        {
            width: 15%;
        }
        .style4
        {
            height: 39px;
            width: 28%;
        }
        .style5
        {
            width: 28%;
        }
        .style6
        {
            height: 20px;
            width: 15%;
        }
        .style7
        {
            height: 20px;
            width: 28%;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>

Comment: I'd suggest you ask that as a separate question...and then accept this as the answer that helped you. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the samples at http://www.ext.net/.  They have a lot of ASP.NET controls that you may find easier to work with if you're not comfortable handling a lot of HTML/CSS on your own.  Specifically, check out the viewport (but others will apply too) -- http://examples.ext.net/#/ViewPort/Basic/Built_in_CodeBehind/

Comment: thanks for your response. do you have any more specific code examples or suggestions?

Comment: You can also check out the UFrame -- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/uframe.aspx for a cool way to handle IFrames.

Comment: there a lot of extensions in ext.net and I'm not exactly sure which would be best to use. What are the best plugins / controls off ext.net that you would recommend for tackling this issue and how would I add them to the code? I downloaded the Ext.NET 1.0 RC1 Community Edition Zip File and manually added the controls to the VS Toolbox

Comment: If you download the examples or go to http://examples.ext.net/#/ViewPort/Basic/Built_in_Markup/ and click on "Source Code" on the top left, you can see the markup used to create the example.  The regions are defined as "North, South, East and West, making the layout pretty straight forward.  I would suggest downloading the examples and playing around with the markup to try to get something close to what you'd like.  If you drag the ViewPort control from the VS Toolbox, it should automatically add the required "Register" statement to your ASPX page (the examples will already be ready to go)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I had good experiences with the (commercial) [ASPxSplitter control](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxperiencedemos/Splitter/LiveResizing.aspx) from DevExpress.

Comment: thanks for your response. do you have any more specific code examples or suggestions?

Comment: @Brian On the page I linked to, there are 9 different examples on how to use the splitter. For me, this was sufficient. You could always ask further questions in the DevExpress support forums.